# How to use pthread on Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt-creator

I want to execute a following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void output() {
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t(output);
    t.join();

    return 0;
}
```

I can't execute it.

Qt Creator outputs 
        terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
          what():  Operation not permitted

However I can execute on the terminal using the option of -pthread.
Could you tell me how to use the option of -pthread in Qt Creator?

My developing environment is Ubuntu(12.04), g++4.6.3, Qt Creator(2.4.1).

Thank you.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You also need to link against `-pthread`. If you use `g++ main.cpp -std=c++0x -pthread` you are doing all that in one step, so it works correctly. To make Qt do the correct things, add the following to your project file:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x -pthread 
LIBS += -pthread
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is not working. Qt Creator outputs terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what(): . However, in Debug, it is working. What does this mean?

Comment: @hizz did you rebuild your project after changing the .pro file?

Comment: Oh, it is working after rebuilding the project. I'll be careful from now on.

Comment: Thank you, It works for me. The only one needed is the last statement.

Comment: @bamboon I've include pthread, why I still need set LIBS, That really confuse me.

Comment: @benhuan You need to do that because you also need to tell the linker that you want to use pthreads.

Comment: It still does not work for me :(. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ja4mwqdp8l50qsg/2014-07-30-202730_1440x900_scrot.png is the link to the screenshot!

Comment: @yash101 You just need LIBS += -pthread and what's important, you have to BUILD it, not just to run it... To build press Ctrl + B and then run it.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = 
DEPENDPATH += .
INCLUDEPATH += .

# Input
SOURCES += test.cpp

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=gnu++0x -pthread
QMAKE_CFLAGS += -std=gnu++0x -pthread
```

Your example compiles and executes correctly with the above .pro file on my system.

Try save your example as test.cpp, and the above as project.pro in same directory.  Then type:

```
$ qmake
$ make
$ ./project
Hello World
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, it is not working. Qt Creator outputs terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Operation not permitted.

Comment: Sorry I made a typo.  Try again.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it is also not working. I have confirmation of a execution by typing "g++ test.cpp -std=c++0x -pthread" or "g++ test.cpp -std=gnu0x -pthread" on terminal. What could be wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Try again with the new .pro file above.  And paste the output of make in your answer.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried it, but it is not working. Qt Creator outputs terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  . However, in Debug mode, it is working. What does it mean?

Comment: When make executes it will show you the gcc command lines it is using to compile and link the executable.  Copy and paste these command lines into your question.  For some reason the Makefile qmake is generating does not have the correct command-line to link threading in release mode.

Comment: I forgot to rebuild the project. Try not to make rudimentary error, I'll be careful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add your command line arguments here:
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.4/creator-run-settings.html

Comment: Thank you. Can I add build option here?